# Does a small hole in a wallpaper require a complete wall redo?

Tags: repair, wallpaper

A small part of the wall came off when it got stuck to the back of a table (I don't know how, honestly).

My landlord claims she needs to redo the entire wall of 11square metres and has some quotes for about 150€.

Is this reasonable? I expect so, as I can't find anything online that could fix this.

[image]

Comment: For yourself, it can probably just be patched or covered over with something.  For a landlord wanting to rent  to someone else, a redo is the best.  Even if piece can be removed from table and placed back on wall, it will be able to be found if looking.

Comment: It's likely that a redo will be necessary, but, if you have the piece that got torn out, you may consider getting a couple of quotes yourself to see what the prices are like. You may find that it'll cost nearly as much to get it repaired as to get the whole wall redone. You may find that someone will do a _nice_ job for very little money. If that's the case, call the landlord back and ask if the repair is OK. If not, you're only out the little bit you spent trying to get it patched - that is the amount you've got to be willing to gamble.

Comment: That wallpaper has been painted over   Patch prime paint